# android video recording with emulator

Tags: android

1) is it possible to record videos and audios using android emulator(using webcam) ? , and storing the recorded video or audio into the pc possibly as

recorder.setOutputFile("C:/test.mp4");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) page it is not possible to record videos, see section "Emulator Limitations":

> No support for camera/video capture
>   (input).

Audio recording is supported by the emulator, you can use the `-audio-in` switch when starting the emulator to specify the audio backend